# CRA + Yarn 2 + jsconfig.json = Can't run unit tests

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg-v2, vscode-jsconfig

I have the following configuration in my `jsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Which lets me do this:

```js
import { App } from 'components'
import * as actions from 'actions/app.actions'
```

Instead of this:

```js
import { App } from '../components'
import * as actions from '../actions/app.actions'
```

To get started with unit testing, I've created a simple `App.test.jsx` in `src/components/tests`

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { App } from 'components'

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  render(<App />)
})
```

However, when I run `yarn test` (which is sugar for `react-scripts test`), it throws with this ugly error:

```
 FAIL  src/components/tests/App.test.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your application tried to access components, but it isn't declared in your dependencies; 
this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.

    Required package: components (via "components")
    Required by: C:\Users\Summer\Code\sandbox\src\components\tests\

      23714 |     enumerable: false
      23715 |   };
    > 23716 |   return Object.defineProperties(new Error(message), {
            |                                  ^
      23717 |     code: { ...propertySpec,
      23718 |       value: code
      23719 |     },

      at internalTools_makeError (.pnp.js:23716:34)
      at resolveToUnqualified (.pnp.js:24670:23)
      at resolveRequest (.pnp.js:24768:29)
      at Object.resolveRequest (.pnp.js:24846:26)
```

It seems like Jest (or Yarn?) thinks `components` is a node package, because it's not aware of the absolute imports setting in my `jsconfig.json`. Is there a way to make it aware? Or do I have to choose between 0% coverage and relative imports?

I've tried entering `"moduleNameMapper"` under `"jest"` in my `package.json` like the documentation explains, but it didn't help. I got the same error + one more after it.

I've also tried changing `components` in the test file to `../components` but then it complains about `actions/app.actions` which is inside the `<App />` component.

Module name mapper config:

```json
/* package.json */
{
  /* ... */
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "actions(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/actions$1",
      "assets(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/assets$1",
      "components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components$1",
      "mocks(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/mocks$1",
      "pages(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/pages$1",
      "reducers(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/reducers$1",
      "scss(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/scss$1",
      "store(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/store$1",
      "themes(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/themes$1",
      "api": "<rootDir>/src/api.js",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your configuration `moduleNameMapper` that you did try?

Comment: @tmhao2005 sure I'll edit it into the question

Comment: Hmm. Things look fine. Do you have a minimal reproducible repo anyway?

Comment: @tmhao2005 Not yet. I was sort of hoping that I wasn't the only person to use CRA on Yarn 2 in VS Code with absolute imports and write unit tests in Jest.  I'll see about putting something together soon~ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Yarn takes control of the resolution pipeline, and thus isn't aware of resolution directives coming from third-party configuration (like `moduleNameMapper`).

This isn't to say you have no options, though - specifically, the fix here is to avoid `moduleNameMapper`, and instead leverage the builtin `link:` dependency protocol. This has other advantages, such as being compatible with all tools (TS, Jest, ESLint, ...) without need to port your aliases to each configuration format.

See also: [Why is the `link:` protocol recommended over aliases for path mapping?](https://yarnpkg.com/features/protocols#why-is-the-link-protocol-recommended-over-aliases-for-path-mapping)